# Error when call prediction with base 64 input

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, tensorflow-hub

I am using Tensorflow hub's example to export a saved_model to be serve with Tensorflow serving using Docker. (https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py)

I just followed some instruction on the internet and modified the export_model like below

```
def export_model(module_spec, class_count, saved_model_dir):
  """Exports model for serving.

  Args:
    module_spec: The hub.ModuleSpec for the image module being used.
    class_count: The number of classes.
    saved_model_dir: Directory in which to save exported model and variables.
  """
  # The SavedModel should hold the eval graph.
  sess, in_image, _, _, _, _ = build_eval_session(module_spec, class_count)

  # Shape of [None] means we can have a batch of images.
  image = tf.placeholder(shape=[None], dtype=tf.string)

  with sess.graph.as_default() as graph:
    tf.saved_model.simple_save(
        sess,
        saved_model_dir,
        #inputs={'image': in_image},
        inputs = {'image_bytes': image},
        outputs={'prediction': graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')},
        legacy_init_op=tf.group(tf.tables_initializer(), name='legacy_init_op')
    )
```

The problem is when i try to call the api using postman it came with this error

```
{
    "error": "Tensor Placeholder_1:0, specified in either feed_devices or fetch_devices was not found in the Graph"
}
```

Do I need to modify the retraining process so it can accept base64 input?

Comment: Hi naotee, is your issue resolved now? Else, the code you are using might be deprecated and that might be the reason for the Error, as this statement was present in the link you specified, 

"WARNING: This code is deprecated in favor of
https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/tree/master/tensorflow_hub/tools/make_image_classifier". You can try with the latest link. Thanks!